# Qt5 won't send timeout signal

Tags: c++, qt5, qtimer

I'm new to QT5, and I'm having a very strange problem.
I want to use QTimer to read coordinate from serial device every 0.5 second, but the QTimer won't send timeout signal.

My .h:

```
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void test();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

My .cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QTimer myTimer(this);
    myTimer.setInterval(500);
    myTimer.setSingleShot(false);
    connect(&myTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(test()));
    myTimer.start();
}

void MainWindow::test() {
    qDebug() << "Time out";
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

After I started the program, not a single "Time out" shows up...

I added the following codes after "myTimer.start()":

```
QTime t = QTime::currentTime().addMSecs(550);
while (QTime::currentTime() < t) {
    qDebug() << myTimer.remainingTime();
}
```

And I found that after the remaining time of "myTimer" reduced to 0, it won't refill the remaining time and start once again, it remains at 0.

Q_OBJECT is already added

Anyone got an idea?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please copy-paste your actual code when asking. The first snippet won't compile as `myTimer` and `mytimer` are different identifiers, and `};` is not a valid syntax to finish function argument list.

Comment: Where in your code do you declare `QTimer myTimer;` and write subsequent lines?

Comment: @Sergey Sorry, I've just edited my question, I pasted the .h and .cpp files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QTimer myTimer(this);
    myTimer.setInterval(500);
    myTimer.setSingleShot(false);
    connect(&myTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(test()));
    myTimer.start();
}
```

In the constructor you declared `myTimer` automatically, so it will be destroyed as soon as constructor returns. This way, by the time when you expect timeout event, `myTimer` does not exist anymore and thus it cannot send any signals!

The solution is straightforward: `myTimer` should exist all the time `MainWindow` object lives, so declare it in the class, not in it's constructor, and allocate it dynamically:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void test();

private:
    QTimer *myTimer; // <--- pointer declaration.
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    // Allocating actual QTimer object:
    myTimer = new QTimer(this);
    // Calling methods by object pointer:
    myTimer->setInterval(500);
    myTimer->setSingleShot(false);
    connect(myTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(test()));
    myTimer->start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    // Don't forget to delete after usage.
    delete myTimer;
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

myTimer is local.

Make it a class member and use it. It will work.